# How to bubble error correctly from Promise without throw?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have the following `TypeScript` method which returns a promise:

```
public loadSavedLogin(): ng.IPromise<MyApp.Models.User> {
   return this._myAppService.getUser(this.savedUserId).then((result: MyApp.Models.User) => {
       if (result) {
          this.userId = result.UserID;
          this.userName = result.UserName;
        }
        return result;
     }, (error) => {
           this._isAuthError = true;
           return  error;
     }
  );
}
```

The problem I have is in the promise's `error` callback. The upstream calls to this method also rely on a promise so if the error does not bubble up correctly, the upstream promise doesn't function correctly. I found a *hackish* solution:

```
(error) => {

      try {
             this._isAuthError = true;
             return error;
           } catch (e) {
              //If any error occurred above make sure to still throw
              throw error;
           } finally {
                //Allow upstream promises to continue as expected
                throw error;
           }
 }
```

This works but looks, feels, and is probably all wrong. I feel like I'm missing a proper implementation when handling and bubbling errors in a promise. There has to be a more proper/correct way of handling the error function in **this** promise as I've done, and yet still allow upstream promise's making a call to this method to work properly as well when handling their own error function.

How do I get the error to bubble without the series of hackish `throw` statements?

**Note:** It seems redundant to return the error and throw as well, but the `IPromise` interface I'm using will not compile if I don't return a value. This is why I return and throw the error.

**Note:** I read a ton of the questions on handling errors with promises, but none of them are answering the question as I'm asking in regards to preventing the hackish approach I've taken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not conversant with TypeScript, but here is a javascript solution, where you use `$q.reject`

```
.then(function() {}, 
      function(error) {
          this._isAuthError = true; 
          return $q.reject(error); 
      });`
```

Comment: ...or `Promise.reject(error)` with [ECMA6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)

Comment: I had tried this as well but it does not work properly at runtime. The desired result is not achieved like in the sample I used. In the constructor of my `TypeScript` class I have `this._q = $q;`. So then in the `error` function I tried: `this._q.reject(error);` It builds fine but doesn't seem to properly bubble the error. Is something else required?

Comment: Sorry the last statement of the function should be `return $q.reject(error)`

Comment: @atconway : unless you're redefining `$q`, why do you need to store it in your class?

Comment: @spender - yeah in my `TypeScript` class I have it implementing `ng.IQService` as such: `private _q: ng.IQService;` so its not the default `$q` for the purposes of the TS features.

Comment: @Chandermani - That worked and was EXACTLY what I was after. What a much better approach, thanks!!

Comment: Essentially, all you're doing here is "rethrowing after catching". From what I can gather, that appears to be the common approach to bubble up errors via promises.

Answer (score 0):

Just throw the error instead of *ever* returning it:

```
public loadSavedLogin(): ng.IPromise<MyApp.Models.User> {
   return this._myAppService.getUser(this.savedUserId).then((result: MyApp.Models.User) => {
       if (result) {
          this.userId = result.UserID;
          this.userName = result.UserName;
        }
        return result;
     }, (error) => {
           this._isAuthError = true;
           throw  error;
     }
  );
}
```

Note that a valid return (i.e. not returning a promise / rejected promise) from a rejection handler makes the next promise in the chain *fulfilled*.

Comment: I actually tried that already, but if see from my note in the OP I states that the `TypeScript` will not build _without_ a `return` statement in the error function. I get the error: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target: Call signatures of types '(result: MyApp.Models.User) => MyApp.Models.User' and '(promiseValue: MyApp.Models.User) => ng.IHttpPromise<{}>' are incompatible: Type 'MyApp.Models.User' is missing property 'success' from type 'ng.IHttpPromise<{}>` This is why I had the `return` in the `Finally` so it sufficed both requirements. How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe you can add a `return null` under the `throw error` to make the TypeScript happy. Of course it will throw before it returns, so this is fine.